# How to resize prechat form?

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, pre-chat

I have a prechat form that is developed as visualforce page. Everything is working fine but when prechat form is shown, it has limited size. Is it possible to change the size of the prechat form ? I came across way to change the size of actual chat window but don't see anything related to prechat form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(500)` and `liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(500)` before the init call of your deployment?

Something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='your source'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(500);
  liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(500);
  liveagent.init('chat url','deployment id', 'org id'));
</script>
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom css styling as well to resize the chat. Although its very old post so You might have resolved. Let me know if not I can show the CSS styles.